# Phonegap data storage mechanism using localStorage-adapter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, local-storage

How do I use this library [localstorage-adapter.js](https://github.com/ccoenraets/phonegap-workshop-max-solutions/blob/master/part07/js/adapters/localstorage-adapter.js) to be able to store data from my server query processing??

I get a library when i see the app from [Christophe Coenraets](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/06/sample-mobile-phonegap-application-with-backbone-js-and-ratchet/) then I want to try it into my application.

My code to access data from server :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#loading_panel').show();
   get_news();

    function get_news(){
       var serviceURL = "http://www.mydomain.com/api/";
       var SistemPakar;
       $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : serviceURL + 'news.php',
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function(x) {
                    if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                         x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                    }
                },
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                        AllData = data.items;
                        if(AllData==''){
                            $('#loading_panel').hide();
                            $('#empty').show();
                        }else{
                            $('#loading_panel').hide();
                            $('#tampilData').show();
                            $.each(AllData, function(index, loaddata) {
                                var data = loaddata.id;
                                var image = loaddata.img;
                                var tanggal = loaddata.tanggal;
                                var strExplode = tanggal.split("-");
                                var strJoinExplode = strExplode[2]+ '-' +strExplode[1]+ '-' +strExplode[0];
                            $('#sispakList').append(
                                '<img src="logo/'+image+'.png"/>'+
                                '<h4>' + loaddata.judul + '</h4>' +
                                '<p>' + loaddata.isi +'</p>' +
                                '<p>' + strJoinExplode + '</p>');
                            });
                            $('#sispakList').listview('refresh');
                            }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                        $('#loading_panel').hide();
                        $('#conn_failed').show();
                    }
            }); 
    }
});
```

How do when the data is first captured by the results of the application and use localstorage-adapter.js to save the data as a mechanism that made ​​Christophe Coenraets on the application??